# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined in Yepnope 2.0.0

Tags: javascript, modernizr, yepnope

I've tried this in Yepnope 2.0.0

```
var something = true;

yepnope({
    test: something,
    yep: 'library1.js',
    nope: 'library2.js' 
    });
```

But doesn't works and returns me in console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined
```

I used Modernizr.load and ever works! But is deprecated in Modernizr 3.0 ...

Fixed it using previous version (v1.5.4) https://github.com/SlexAxton/yepnope.js/releases but any ideas using 2.0.0?

---

Example using YepNope 1.x
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/76885657/stackoverflow/yepnope/yepnope1.html

Same code, using YepNope 2.x
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/76885657/stackoverflow/yepnope/yepnope2.html

Comment: can you post a code sample showing the problem, the browser you are using, etc

Comment: The code sample is shown, the browser Google Chrome

Comment: a code sample that shows the issue. online. like on jsbin.com or something

Comment: Thanks @Patrick, I added online examples!

Comment: Hi @lucasgabmoreno I know its very old discussion. I'm also facing same issue. How you fixed this?